# UnsupportedClassVersionError... but with same JAVA version

Tags: java

I am trying to migrate a tomcat server.

Both are using `tomcat7` version and all is supossed to be ready to take my java/jsp files from one server to another. 
I did and I got `UnsupportedClassVersionError` error. 
It was normal as in the old one I had `JRE 1.8 version` and in the new installation I had `JRE 1.7 version` (both from Oracle).

I proceeded to upgrade the second to 1.8. And everything was fine as in the new the output for `java -version` is:

> java version "1.8.0_191" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.8.0_191-b12) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)

While in the old one:

> java version "1.8.0_131" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.8.0_131-b11) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

In both echo $JAVA_HOME outputs:

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

I restarted tomcat and server itself... but the `UnsupportedClassVersionError` persists.

I don't know if:

- Somewhere I still point to the JRE 1.7 installation
- Or `1.8.0_191` is considered another version than `1.8.0_131`

Note: the compiler is the same as they have not been recompiled. Just take the compiled ones from old server (where there is no problem version) to the new one.

Has anyone a hint for me?

Thank you very much

Comment: 1.8.0_191 has the same .class file version as 1.8.0_131.

Comment: Yes, that's what I think, so where is the mistake?

Comment: @jaume: however you restart the server probably doesn't look at JAVA_HOME. JAVA_HOME is weird, because while *some scripts* look at it, others just use whatever is on the stack or use some other way of figuring out which JVM to use.

Comment: @JoachimSauer thanks, so what would you suggest to force it? Maybe remove jre 1.7?

Comment: @jaume: if you don't need 1.7 installed for anything else, then removing it is probably the easiest way to get there. At the very least it'll help you find out why Tomcat still runs with that version.

Comment: Have a look at the scripts/config files that tomcat is using, the path might be hardcoded there or it is using some other environment variable.

Comment: @Thomas: It's a clean installation. Which files would you suggest to check? server.xml,catalina.sh, web.xml... doesn't seem to be the problem

Comment: You need to look at the startup script that control the background Tomcat process, since that script likely hardcodes the path to Java. You didn't share which Linux version you're using, so difficult to be more specific about where that file is, but it's likely an `initd` or `systemd` file, not a file in the Tomcat folders.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with plain Tomcat but I'd suggest looking at `catalina.sh` or maybe there's some configuration file (could be named `catalina.conf`) that this script is calling.

Comment: @Andreas: it's ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Digging in @JoachimSauer 's way, I managed to find which package was representing java 1.7 in my case (openjdk-7-jre-headless) and removed it. Previously I also removed with the command "update-alternatives --remove "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java" ". At the end no package or reference was made to java 1.7 and it works.

Comment: @JoachimSauer why don't you post it as a solution in order to accept it?

Comment: Btw, I followed also @Andreas way, but didn't find a solution in those files

Comment: @jaume: I didn't provide an answer, I just helped you find it. Feel free to self-answer (and accept, if it helped solve your problem), that's actually quite appreciated around here.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: ok! much appreciated your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed in comments, sometimes JAVA_HOME is not checked and the decision on what jvm should be used is taken with another criteria (can't say which ones). So removing the old version of java forced the process to choose the desired one as it was unique.